# Is it possible to ignore/not parse some javascript code when using Laravel Mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel-mix

When using the `mix.js` command, e.g. `mix.js('somefile-dev.js', 'somefile-production.js');` In Laravel Mix is it possible to ignore/*not parse* some JavaScript code within that file? In the same way it's possible to use something like `/* eslint-disable */`

If so, what is the comment statement I need to use?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand my question – maybe I need to re-phrase it. I'm not looking to comment out JavaScript. I'm trying to understand if there's a way to prevent Laravel Mix from parsing some JavaScript code

Comment: one workaround is to put the code you want ignored in an `eval()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it is not possible to use comments to prevent parsing. However, there are some other solutions that may help:

1. **Copy the files instead**: You could simply copy the file rather than process it with mix – https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/copying-files
2. **If you have multiple JavaScript files that reference each other, make sure you're *mixing* the files**. I realised I ran into my particular JS error was because I had broken up the scripts into separate files, and then I processed them with Mix using `mix.js` rather than concatenating the files together with `mix.scripts`. I assume since Mix garbles the variable names, it wasn't aware that two variables from different scripts should be the same abstraction